# Send keystrokes and string to gdb terminal

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, terminal, vim8

I started debugging a c program inside vim with:

```
:packadd termdebug
:Termdebug
```

with vim 8 and and gdb > 8.3 installed.

In order to set a breakpoint, I would like to send the following string while the cursor is in file main.c (by typing `<leader>b`):

```
break fileName:lineNumber
```

so that the gdb terminal receives:

```
break main.c:100
```

if the file name is `main.c` and the current line for this example is 100 and represented with `let lineNumber = line('.')`

Here is what I've come up with until now:

```
nnoremap <leader>b : call SetBreakPoint()<CR>
function! SetBreakPoint() abort
    let lineNumber = line('.')
    let fileName = %f
    exe "normal! ma"
    exe "normal! \<C-w>w\<C-w>w" | call term_sendkeys('', "break fileName\:lineNumber\<CR>")
    exe "normal! \<C-w>w`a"
endfunction
```

The line `exe "normal! \<C-w>w\<C-w>w | call term_sendkeys()..."` takes into account that the cursor is in a file named main.c and has to traverse Nerdtree to arrive to the Terminal window opened by vim with gdb.
I have in total 3 vim windows (main.c, Nerdtree and Terminal (gdb)).

The problem here is that I cannot make `term_sendkeys()` load the values of fileName and lineNumber.

However, changing the longest line of code to

```
exe "normal! \<C-w>w\<C-w>w" | call term_sendkeys('', "break main.c:100\<CR>")
```

works but defeats the whole purpose of defining break points inside the vim main.c window without having to manually change window and type in the break command for gdb.

Thanks

Comment: `call term_sendkeys('', "break " . fileName . ':' . lineNumber . "\<CR>")` or something like that.

Comment: Why not use `:h :Break` ?  If you really need to do some customization, consider `TermDebugSendCommand`.

Comment: @Matt I cannot dereference the value of fileName inside your command, how do you output the value of fileName and lineNumber inside term_sendkeys?